# Mac command-line sort files into subfolders

Tags: macos, command-line, find, terminal.app

I want to run a command on a very large folder to sort every item into subfolders based on modification date. Can this be done with one line?

I.e., all files modified in July 2013 would be moved to `2013-07` etc.

Something with `find`.... parse the year/month, then move to matching folder.

The `man` page for Mac's `find` is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090501221803809) ... and modified it for my needs:

```
for f in 12*; do   
     dir='/foo/bar/'$(stat -f%Sm -t%Y-%m "$f")
     [ -d "$dir" ] || mkdir "$dir"
     mv -nv "$f" "$dir"/
done
```

You can replace the `m` in `-f%Sm` with any of the following:

**a, m, c, B**

- The time file was last **a**ccessed or **m**odified, of when the inode was
  last **c**hanged, or the **B**irth time of the inode.